# array of dictionaries & mem mgmt

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have an array of dictionaries, which works ok.  I am trying to track down a memory access issue and want to know:

If I create autoreleased strings for the dictionary, for example one string is from:

```
NSArray *dirContents = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] contentsOfDirectoryAtPath:path error:&error];
for (NSString *file in dirContents)
```

When I do

```
NSDictionary *dictItem = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:file, @"file"...
```

Does the resulting dictItem retain the individual strings?  I have been assuming so ;-)

And then I add that dictItem to an array.  I assume the addObject call on NSMutableArray will retain the dictItem for me...

What about when it comes time to free up the memory?
If I simply call removeAllObjects on the array (which crashes now), will it release all of the strings inside the dictionaries as well as the dictionaries themselves?

Hope this is somewhat understandable ;-)

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick whistle-stop tour of memory management in Cocoa collections...

- NSDictionary does not retain keys.  Instead it creates a copy of the key.  In other words adding an object as a key in a dictionary will not increment its retain count.
- NSDictionary will retain the values for the keys that you pass it.
- When you release (and eventually dealloc) the NSDictionary it is responsible for calling release on the objects it has stored (not you!)
- NSArray will retain any object you add to it
- NSArray will release all objects it holds a reference to when it is deallocated

Knowing the above...

- dicItem will not retain your key @"file" - it will copy it
- dicItem will retain your object called file
- when dicItem is deallocated it will call release on its copy of @"file" and file
- when you add a dicItem to your array it will be retained
- when you release your array and it is deallocated all the dicItems it holds will be sent a release message
- releasing your array should subsequently trigger a dealloc of your dicItem objects - provided they are referenced elsewhere (i.e. leaked)
- you do not need to send your NSArray object a removeAllObjects message - the array itself will clean up after itself.

Comment: thanks! That makes sense!  Looks like I am basically using it correct, just was unaware of what was a copy and what was a retain.  The dictItems are the only needed copies for my app.  The removeAllObjects was to handle a "refresh" where I want to reuse the array.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are making this a little more complicated than it has to be. The only memory management you need to really worry about is within your own classes. When adding to an NSArray it does in fact retain the object, and then when you call removeAllObjects or the array is destroyed, it will release all of it's contained objects. However, this is where the concept of "owning" an object is important. When any object gets a reference to an object, it can call "retain" on it to indicate that it owns the object (this also applies to allocating a new object or using the "new" operator). That means, the object knows for sure the object will be around until it is done with it. To indicate that it is done with the object, it should always release or autorelease the object and set the reference to nil.

So bottom line, if you do not call retain, alloc, or new on an object, you should never call release. If you do call one of those functions, you should ALWAYS call release or autorelease on it. For any other object that you may send a reference to, you can assume that it will take ownership of it if it wants and if it does, it will always release it when it is done.